# Are helicopters expected to follow the lateral guidance of taxiways in a hover taxi or air taxi?

Tags: air-traffic-control, taxiing

If a helicopter is asked by ATC to hover taxi or air taxi, are they still expected to follow the lateral guidance of taxiways on the ground, or do they proceed "as the crow flies", direct to their destination?

Comment: How can one hover _and_ taxi? One negates the other

Answer (score 2):

Yes, unless given an explicit clearance to hover taxi direct to a location on an airfield.

Comment: The question is phrased as “which of options A or B applies”? “Yes” is ambiguous.